# R function won't print sums of individual items in lists

Tags: r, list, printing

I have a list of lists called "thalachbysite" with 4 lists in it, and each inner list has several hundred items.

I want to get the sum of each inner list, so I tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(thalachbysite)) {
  sum(thalachbysite[[i]])
}
```

My output is completely empty though - it accepts the input with no error or warnings, but my screen remains blank. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why this is confusing but basically, `for` loops return NULL. So if you put your `sum` in a loop, you need to explicitly print or return the value, for example to print:

```
l <- list(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
for(i in 1:length(l)) {print(sum(l[[i]]))}
[1] 55
[1] 155
```

That said - a `for` loop is not a good solution in this case. Better to use an `apply` function, such as `lapply` or `sapply`:

```
lapply(l, sum)
$x
[1] 55

$y
[1] 155

sapply(l, sum)
  x   y 
 55 155
```